# Cloud Messaging scheduled sending does not work

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi guys as the title suggests I have a problem regarding Firebase Cloud Messaging, everything works perfectly even when the device does not open the app for a long time, receives notifications perfectly, but the problem occurs when I schedule the daily notification via the console firebase li the first time of sending works and sends the notification to all devices, while the next day at the scheduled time the notification is no longer received and this problem I do not know how to solve it, I have tried everything without any solution, the daily notifications do not are received, can you help me thanks.

```
@SuppressLint("MissingFirebaseInstanceTokenRefresh")
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    /*public static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;*/
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";
    public static String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.fourapper.forpaper.channel";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        generateNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());

    }

    private void generateNotification(String body, String title) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        /*PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 0 , new Intent[]{intent}, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);*/
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        /*NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);*/
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_forpapaer)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{100, 500})
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentInfo("info")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = null;
        if (intent.hasExtra(NOTIFICATION)) {
            notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        }

        int notificationId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);

        /*if(NOTIFICATION_ID > 2147483646){
            NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;
        }*/

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel");
            notificationChannel.setBypassDnd(true);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{ 0, 500});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }

        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
    }
}
```

below the token

```
public class GettingDeviceTokenService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String deviceToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        assert deviceToken != null;
        Log.d("Device Token", deviceToken);
    }
}
```

Below are the photos of the firebase cloud messaging console for scheduled daily sending at 12:00 AM Recipient Time Zone

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

sending setting change screen

[image: sending setting change screen]

Comment: You might want to add `?hl=en` to the URL of the Firebase console to switch it to English,, and retake the screenshots, as it'll drastically increase the number of people who can understand them.

Comment: yes I just added the screens in English so that everyone can understand

Comment: Thanks for that: much easier to read. :)   To clarify: it says "Once per user for this message", which means that each user will only receive the message once (no matter how many days the campaign runs for). Is that what you're asking about? Or is the problem with new users, who haven't received the message on any of the previous days yet?

Comment: the problem that sends scheduled notifications only once per user and then does not send them anymore, now that you have pointed out this thing, it may depend on this fact since now I have put this option:

Comment: see above in the last screen

Comment: because from what I read now it sends 1 message every day, right?

Comment: From what I see in that last screen it might indeed send up to one message per day.

Comment: I tried this new configuration and nothing came, the scheduled notifications do not arrive and I don't know why